# Mocked method always returns empty Optional

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

So I'm new to Unit Testing.

I'm trying to test the behavior of the method findAll() in IngredientServiceImplTest.

The problem that I'm facing has to do with the return value of the method mocked. It always return empty thus throwing the exception.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

*Testing class.*

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class IngredientServiceImplTest {
   @Mock
   private MenuItemIngredientRepository menuItemIngredientRepository;

   @Mock
   private IngredientRepository ingredientRepository;

   @InjectMocks
   private IngredientServiceImpl ingredientService;

   @Mock
   private JpaRepository<Ingredient, Long> jpaRepository;

   @Mock
   private BaseMapper<IngredientCreateDto, IngredientUpdateDto, IngredientResponseDto, 
   Ingredient> baseMapper;


   @BeforeEach
   void init() {
       ingredientService.jpaRepository = jpaRepository;
       ingredientService.baseMapper = baseMapper;
   }

  @Test
  void When_FindById_ReturnIngredient() {

      Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
      ingredient.setId(1L);
      ingredient.setName("Name");

      IngredientCreateDto ingredientCreateDto = new IngredientCreateDto();
      ingredientCreateDto.setName("Name");

      when(jpaRepository.findById(ingredient.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(ingredient));
      when(baseMapper.createDtoToEntity(ingredientCreateDto)).thenReturn(ingredient);
      assertEquals(ingredientService.findById(ingredient.getId()).getName(), 
 
    }
```

*Base service class*

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseServiceImpl<CREATE_DTO, UPDATE_DTO, RESPONSE_DTO, ENTITY> implements BaseService<CREATE_DTO, UPDATE_DTO, RESPONSE_DTO, ENTITY> {

@Autowired
protected JpaRepository<ENTITY, Long> jpaRepository;

@Autowired
protected BaseMapper<CREATE_DTO, UPDATE_DTO, RESPONSE_DTO, ENTITY> baseMapper;

@Override
public List<RESPONSE_DTO> findAll() {
    return jpaRepository.findAll()
                        .stream()
                        .map(baseMapper::entityToResponseDto)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public RESPONSE_DTO findById(Long id) {
    return jpaRepository.findById(id)
            .map(baseMapper::entityToResponseDto)
            .orElseThrow(() -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("Entity with id: " + id + " does not exist!");
            });
}

@Override
public RESPONSE_DTO save(CREATE_DTO entity) {
    return baseMapper.entityToResponseDto(jpaRepository.save(baseMapper.createDtoToEntity(entity)));
}
}
```

*Ingredient Service class*

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class IngredientServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<IngredientCreateDto, IngredientUpdateDto, IngredientResponseDto, Ingredient> implements IngredientService{

private final MenuItemIngredientRepository menuItemIngredientRepository;
private final IngredientRepository ingredientsRepository;

@Override
public IngredientResponseDto update(Long id, IngredientUpdateDto ingredient) {
    super.findById(id);
    Ingredient entityIngredient = baseMapper.updateDtoToEntity(ingredient);
    entityIngredient.setId(id);
    entityIngredient.setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
    return baseMapper.entityToResponseDto(jpaRepository.save(entityIngredient));

}

@Override
public List<IngredientResponseDto> findTopIngredients(Integer n) {
    return menuItemIngredientRepository.findTopIngredients(n)
            .stream()
            .map(id -> baseMapper.entityToResponseDto(jpaRepository.getOne(id)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public List<IngredientResponseDto> findAllByFilter(IngredientFilter ingredientFilter) {
    return ingredientsRepository.findAllByFilter(ingredientFilter)
            .stream()
            .map(ingredient -> baseMapper.entityToResponseDto(ingredient))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}


}
```

Comment: What exception or output do you see? At a guess `entityToResponseDto` is returning `null` from the mock `baseMapper` and you need to add another `when` for `baseMapper.entityToResponseDto`.

Comment: The exception thrown is "Entity with id: " + id + " does not exist!" which is the exception throw by findById method at BaseServiceImpl class.

Comment: Thank a lot man! That fixed the problem!

Comment: Nice. I can see this would be a little painful to step through with a debugger, with the mocks and method reference style. You could switch from method reference style `baseMapper::entityToResponseDto` to lambda style `(ingredient -> baseMapper.entityToResponseDto(ingredient))` temporarily. Then you could drop a breakpoint in there to check the output of `jpaRepository.findById`, or print some debug info.